# HTTP DELETE Operation using DocuSign API

Tags: docusignapi

We are using DocuSign Rest API from our Pega application. There is a scenario where we have to delete a particular recipient, and the restful service for this functionality is an HTTP DELETE which expects a message body (JSON format).

But Pega has certain limitation in sending message body for HTTP DELETE requests and hence we are now unable to hit the DocuSign Rest API for Delete Recipient.

[API](https://www.docusign.com/p/RESTAPIGuide/Content/REST%20API%20References/Delete%20Recipients%20from%20an%20Envelope.htm) for Docusign

Pega provides some workaround in such scenarios where there is a message body required for DELETE operations.

Can you please let me know if DocuSign provides an alternate way to invoke the service without a message body? We want this information to decide if we need to go the Pega way or DocuSign way to fix this issue.

Comment: The documentation link you are referring to is for older documentation. I have added the new documentation link in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can delete the recipient by **specifying the recipientId** in the URL.

See [deleteEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/delete/) api

> DELETE /v2/accounts/{accId}/envelopes/{envId}/recipients/**{recipientId}**

---

The api you are using is [deleteListEnvelopeRecipients](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/EnvelopeRecipients/deleteList/)

Use deleteListEnvelopeRecipients api if you want to delete multiple recipients in a single call. You will have to specify the HTTP body for this call.